# adding .net code to a asp webforms website, can't reference namespaces in .dll file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some problem with my first task . i made a asp.net web form app i add some dll libraries in my "webform1.aspx.cs" file but after some time these are showing partially hide.

thank you for your help!

======================CLARIFICATION====================

when i put my cursor on these libraries it show that this using directives are not necessary . when i view solution and want fix it . this ll remove my directives from the top. but i want these directives remain same and active.
kindly help me

Comment: Is code from these dlls used in some of your .net code?  If Visual Studio detects that none of it is being used, it may be marking them as such for efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

Comment :- When you inculde unwanted dll libraries in your project it shows fade like hide beacuse there is no need, and if you have work for these dll then it will show active.